# convert duplicate text on columns to Header (DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have unstructured data retrieved from pdf.

The output as follows:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| name | Mike |
| age | 18 |
| sex | M. |
| name | Angel |
| age | 21 |
| sex | F. |
| name | Brod |
| age | 34 |
| sex | M. |

I want column 1 to be the header of my data Frame(Python) (name, sex, age)

Comment: Hi, please adding what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `index` column that will gather the groups and then pivot using it.

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "1": ["name", "age", "sex", "name", "age", "sex", "name", "age", "sex"],
    "2": ["Mike", "18", "M.", "Angel", "21", "F.", "Brod", "34", "M."],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["0"] = [x for x in range(df.shape[0] // 3) for _ in range(3)]
df = df.pivot(index="0", columns="1", values="2")
```

Result:

```
1 age   name sex
0               
0  18   Mike  M.
1  21  Angel  F.
2  34   Brod  M.
```